# Multiple I2C devices connected to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I've got one GY-80 IC and one ms5803 pressure sensor, interfaced to a Pi. Both are working fine. Then I connected the SDA and SCL pins of the sensors and then to Pi. All  of the devices are displayed using the command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1e --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- 53 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 69 -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 77
```

But when I tried to read pressure sensor whose I2C address is id 0x76, it gives the error:

```
File "/home/pi/workspace/src/gy_80/Psensor_node.py", line 50, in main
bus.write_byte(0x76, 0x58)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

`bus.write_byte(0x76,0x1E)`, which is reset command, works perfectly while any other command generates error. The error generating code section is:

```
import smbus 
import time 

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) 
#0x1E(30) Reset command 
bus.write_byte(0x76, 0x1E) 
time.sleep(0.5) 

def main() 
    #0x40(64) Pressure conversion(OSR = 256) 
    command bus.write_byte(0x76, 0x50) ### THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
```

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post your code..

Comment: I'm posting error generating part here.Irony is that bus.write_byte(0x76,0x1E) ,which is reset command works perfectly while any other command generates error.                                       import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

#0x1E(30)       Reset command
bus.write_byte(0x76, 0x1E)
time.sleep(0.5)
def main()
#0x40(64)       Pressure conversion(OSR = 256) command
                       bus.write_byte(0x76, 0x50)  ### THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR

Answer (score 1):

For connecting multiple slaves with exact same address you will need I2C multiplexer.

Like one mentioned **[here](http://www.gadgetexplained.com/2016/04/how-to-connect-multiple-i2c-devices_19.html)**

Comment: I'd like to see this verified, but from the i2cdetect output it looks like one device is at 0x76 and the other at 0x77. That should be legal.